# c:foreach ui:repeat not working in <p:menubar> primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<p:tabView scrollable="true" var="tabItem" value="#{rootItem.lstItems}">
 <p:tab title="#{tabItem.txtMenuName}">
    <p:menubar>
        <c:forEach items="#{tabItem.lstItems}" var="menuItem">
            <p:menuitem value="#{menuItem.txtMenuName}" />
        </c:forEach>
    </p:menubar>
       <--<p:menubar>
         <ui:repeat items="#{tabItem.lstItems}" var="menuItem">
            <p:menuitem value="#{menuItem.txtMenuName}" />
         </ui:repeat>
       </p:menubar>
     -->
</p:tab>
```

It works fine in  primefaces 4.0 (netbeans IDE)

But not working in eclipse primefaces 5.0 (eclipse IDE)
However, ui:repeat not working in both cases.

Exception thrown is:

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException:com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions cannot be cast to  org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuElement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI repeat does not work in both cases since menuBar renders it's children itself, not via renderes for menuItem and so it does not 'delegate' to ui:repeat either. If you want dynamic menu's, create a model and use the model attribute to relate the two. Something like done in the [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml):

xhtml:

```
<p:menu model="#{menuView.model}" />
```

java:

```
//First submenu
DefaultSubMenu firstSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Dynamic Submenu");

DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem("External");
item.setUrl("http://www.primefaces.org");
item.setIcon("ui-icon-home");
firstSubmenu.addElement(item);

model.addElement(firstSubmenu);

//Second submenu
DefaultSubMenu secondSubmenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Dynamic Actions");
...
```

Regarding the error, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188092/java-lang-classcastexception-com-sun-faces-facelets-compiler-uiinstructions-can). Removing the comment might help

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I cannot use p:confirm, right?